I am going to have a tool made in China, what is the most cost effective approach for protection in USA and China?
Can I file a utility patent directly with China and bypass a PCT to save money? I would also file a PPA at the same time. My concern is that since the tool is going to be made in China, that I will need patent protection there, over and above the NNN.

Patents give their owner the right to try to stop others from making, selling, offering for sale, importing or using anything that falls under the granted claims.
If your market was only the U.S. or if you were satisfied with your likely profit was from the U.S. you would only technically need a U.S. patent.
To get protection for other markets and alternative protection for the U.S. market you could purse patents in other larger markets and/or in likely locations of manufacturing.
China might be both a large market and a likely location for manufacturing. One does not need to go through the PCT process to get to China or places outside the U.S. but there can be advantages, including cost if you have many places in mind or don’t know where you need to go.
People generally think if you have two or fewer places in mind the cost is less to file directly (or regionally) rather than via PCT. On the other hand a U.S. person can file PCT with the USPTO as the Receiving Office and have time to try to figure out their next steps.
It may be that you need local patent representatives to deal with China’s patent office past the first step in either the PCT or direct case.

Thank you so much for your excellent input Mr White.
I now feel that in my situation, on the scale of Pros and Cons, a PCT weighs heavily on the Pro side, and skip the concerns of trying to save costs.
Ideally, I wanted to market the new tool simultaneously with a book that I have wrote in support of it. I have now decided to market the book first, with the note that the new tool WILL be available in the near future. The tool and book are related to the health and wellness marketplace.
Major appreciation to Stack Exchange and Ask Patents, and again for you Mr White.
The future looks bright !
Gene Anderson

Ask Patents is not a forum. It is a question and answer site. If you have a new question, it needs to be posted as a new question. Otherwise you can edit the original question. As you gain reputation, you will gain the ability to comment.
